# Query Error in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

i write query

```
db.Collection.find({"Date" : { "$last" : "Date" }});
```

to find the last date from the collection having the date as field
it gives

```
Error: error: {
        "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $last",
        "code" : 17287
```

please find me out the error or the way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

[$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) is only available in the `$group` stage.

You can use it as shown below :

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { item: 1, Date: 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$item",
           lastDate: { $last: "$Date" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

TO find the last date from the collection :

> db.Collection.find({},{Date:1,_id:0}).sort({Date:-1}).limit(1).pretty()